# Error en sintaxis de una función DELETE en Visual Basic .NET

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, delete

No logro entender el error en un botón para eliminar una fila. Mi codigo da el error System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Must declare the scalar variable "@artid".'

Este es el código:

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        If MessageBox.Show("Eliminar registro?", "Eliminar registro", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) = DialogResult.Yes Then
            Dim artid As String = TextCodigo.Text
            Dim query As String = "DELETE from Articulo where Codigo =  @artid"

            Using con As New SqlConnection("Data Source=Mi conexion"),
          command As New SqlCommand(query, con)

                con.Open()
                command.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using
            MessageBox.Show("Eliminado correctamente")
            LoadDataInGrid()
        End If
    End Sub
```

El error lo marca en la línea command.ExecuteNonQuery(). Gracias de antemano y perdón si es algo demasiado obvio.

Comment: El error te indica claramente cual es el problema. ¿Qué es `@artid`? No sabe que hay ahí. porque nunca se lo has dado. Tienes que añadirle un parámetro. [Sql Parameters](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0). Aunque el ejemplo de la documentación sea una update, es exactamente lo mismo para una sentencia delete.

Comment: @Javi fer2 ok, pero no entiendo como le doy exactamente? estoy usando visual basic.net, no C#.

Comment: Estás ejecutando la consulta como si la variable de vb.net fuese lo mismo que una variable de SQL Server. Y pues no. No sé casi nada de vb.net pero sé que MSSQL se va a quejar mientras uses una variable T-SQL que no esté definida

Comment: Si te fijas en la documentacion, arriba a la derecha podes cambiar el lenguaje ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El ejemplo de la [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) que te pasaron, no solo es claro, si no que además, esta en VB.NET

La forma mas simple de hacerlo es

```
command.Parameters.Add("@artid", SqlDbType.Int)
command.Parameters("@artid").Value = artid
```

Donde declaras el parámetro, lo agregas a la lista de parámetros, y luego le das el valor.

Fíjate que hay varias formas de agregar parámetros, inclusive, hacerlo todo en una sola instrucción.

Tu código, entonces, debería quedar así:

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    If MessageBox.Show("Eliminar registro?", "Eliminar registro", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) = DialogResult.Yes Then
        Dim artid As String = TextCodigo.Text
        Dim query As String = "DELETE from Articulo where Codigo =  @artid"
        Using con As New SqlConnection("Data Source=Mi conexion"),
          command As New SqlCommand(query, con)
            con.Open()
            command.Parameters.Add("@artid", SqlDbType.Int)
            command.Parameters("@artid").Value = artid 
            command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
        MessageBox.Show("Eliminado correctamente")
        LoadDataInGrid()
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim query As String = "DELETE from Articulo where Codigo =  @artid"
```

Tu error es por que estas usando la `variable` dentro de las comillas, **lo esta tomando como texto no como valor**, esta es la forma correcta cambiando la linea anterior:

```
Dim query As String = "DELETE from Articulo where Codigo='" & artid & "'"
```

Answer (score -1):

Intenta de la siguiente forma:

```vb
Dim artid As String = TextCodigo.Text
Dim query As String = $"DELETE from Articulo where Codigo =  {@artid}"
```

Comment: Esto sirve, sin el @ delante de la variable (no es necesario en el contexto de interpolacion de strings). Pero... Esta respuesta es un pedazo de codigo sin explicacion. Y lo que estas poniendo es muyyyy suceptible a una inyeccion de codigo, mas que el valor viene de un textbox... y creo que lo que busca es como agregar parametros al query.